# Multiple servers in only one TupleSpace in DRb (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, drb

guys!
I'm thinking in to run each server in one computer and to do all clients find themselves.
Is there a way to run multiple servers with DRb?

If not, how can I do my clients (one in each computer too) see all the servers in my network? I'm frustrated.

The idea is to make a simple P2P, where I can run one server and one client in one computer.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

DRb is a fairly low-level means of IPC. You may find the following higher-level solution easier to use although you do have to set up an infrastructure first. You don't say whether you are on Linux or something else, but this works on Linux and runs pretty much out of the box on Gentoo:

- [Jerbil on Github](https://github.com/osburn-sharp/jerbil)
- [A Painless Approach to Ruby Linux Services](http://robert-on-rails.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/a-painless-approach-to-writing-linux.html)